# Icon Label in App-Launcher cutted (no full App name) [Android]

Tags: android, icons, label, launcher

i´ve developed an app and set the appname to something like "xxxTeamViewer" (x are other letters).

When i install the app on a device with 4.03, the app Icon Label in launcher is just "Team".

How to make the label show completely on every device?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't control it. It is controlled by the launcher app, which is a regular Android app, which can be developed  by anyone. You can develop a launcher, which will show all the apps named as for example **dummy** regardless of how are they named in `appname`

Comment: Thanks, nice explained.